# Reshape dataframe

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr, reshape2

I have a dataframe like so:

```
col1  col2  year  mean  median
a     c     2012  14.9  14
a     c     2013  12.1  13 
r     d     2012  11.0  11
r     d     2013  13.1  15
```

I'd like to transform it to:

```
               2012            2013
col1  col2  mean  median    mean  median
a     c     14.9  14        12.1  13
r     d     11.0  11        13.1  15
```

Comment: Based on the expected result showed, third element in `year` would be `2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `reshape`

```
reshape(df1, idvar=c('col1', 'col2'), timevar='year',  direction='wide')
#     col1 col2 mean.2012 median.2012 mean.2013 median.2013
#1    a    c      14.9          14      12.1          13
#3    r    d      11.0          11      13.1          15
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a", "r", "r"), col2 = c("c", "c", 
"d", "d"), year = c(2012, 2013, 2012, 2013), mean = c(14.9, 12.1, 
11, 13.1), median = c(14L, 13L, 11L, 15L)), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "year", "mean", "median"), row.names = c(NA, -4L),
 class =   "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dataframes don't have the capability to hold 2D column headers. See here

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/colnames.html

*For a data frame, value for rownames should be a character vector of non-duplicated and non-missing names (this is enforced), and for colnames a character vector of (preferably) unique syntactically-valid names. In both cases, value will be coerced by as.character, and setting colnames will convert the row names to character.*

Note vectors are 1D in R. This looks more like an Excel representation of the data than R's. If you want to filter by years then you could do something like this:

```
d[d$year == 2012,]
```

assuming your data frame is called d. If you want to drop the year column:

```
d[d$year == 2012, c(1,2,4,5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

From `data.table v1.9.5+`, `dcast` can handle multiple `value.var` columns. We can do:

```
require(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), col1 + col2 ~ year, value.var=c("mean", "median"))
#    col1 col2 2012_mean 2013_mean 2012_median 2013_median
# 1:    a    c      14.9      12.1          14          13
# 2:    r    d      11.0      13.1          11          15
```

where `dat` is your `data.frame`. `setDT()` converts it to `data.table` by reference.

You can get it by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 0):

If you install a Tex package for your unstated OS you can use the `tables` and `Hmisc` packages to deliver something even more like what you requested, since the tabular function is capable of delivering the two-row headers that you specified:

```
require(tables); require(Hmisc)
val <- tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + 
                                                  Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
 Hmisc::latex(val, file="tbl.tex")
```

[image]

When there is a pdflatex in the expected directory, the `"tbl.tex"` file gets passed to it and then on my system at least gets displayed in a pdfviewer named Skim in its .dvi form. I exported it through Preview.app as a .png file which you see above. You could instead not specify a tex file and have the Latex code printed to the R console:

```
Hmisc::latex(val)
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Length} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Width} \\ 
Species  & n & mean & sd & mean & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sd} \\ 
\hline
setosa  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $5.01$ & $0.35$ & $3.43$ & $0.38$ \\
versicolor  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $5.94$ & $0.52$ & $2.77$ & $0.31$ \\
virginica  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $6.59$ & $0.64$ & $2.97$ & $0.32$ \\
All  & $150$ & $5.84$ & $0.83$ & $3.06$ & $0.44$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
> ?latex
> val <- tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*
+ (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
```

There is also an `html` function in Hmisc that will produce HTML table code.